Determining date range of ImageCollection in Google Earth Engine
What are the min and max dates of any image in an image collection?
As an example, I'm using 'GOOGLE/DYNAMICWORLD/V1' though I'd need this to work with any image collection. I've tried looking at the properties:
var dataset_id = 'GOOGLE/DYNAMICWORLD/V1';
console.log(ee.data.getAsset(dataset_id));
// 'properties' is empty

I've also tried asking the API itself what the min/max are, but it takes so long the browser window times out and I never get an answer:
var collection = ee.ImageCollection(dataset_id);
var start_millis = collection.aggregate_min('system:time_start').getInfo()
var end_millis = collection.aggregate_max('system:time_start').getInfo()
// takes so long to run the browser times out.

I also can't statically set the min/max date because these change dynamically for many datasets that are updated daily, like the Google Dynamic World example.

Here's a hack that I've had to use instead in python to pull the date range directly from the dataset description page:
import requests
import re

url = "https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/datasets/catalog/GOOGLE_DYNAMICWORLD_V1#bands"
r = requests.get(url)
match = re.search(r"Dataset Availability.*?(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})T.*?(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})T", r.text, re.DOTALL)
if match:
    start_date, end_date = match.groups()
    print("Start:", start_date)
    print("End:", end_date)


EE is indexing the properties of image collection assets, allowing for really efficient filtering. You can use this to efficiently reduce the number of images used to find your range. The snippet below find the start from images with date less or equal to the first image in the collection. The end is found within the last month.
var collection = ee.ImageCollection('GOOGLE/DYNAMICWORLD/V1')
var start_millis = collection
  .filter(ee.Filter.lte('system:time_start', collection.first().get('system:time_start')))
  .reduceColumns(ee.Reducer.min(), ['system:time_start'])
  .getNumber('min')
  
var now = ee.Date(new Date())
var end_millis = collection
  .filterDate(now.advance(-1, 'month'), now)
  .reduceColumns(ee.Reducer.max(), ['system:time_start'])
  .getNumber('max')

https://code.earthengine.google.com/40d2bff3ffdfe6dca888512e52c5e658

Thank you but like you said, this only works if the image collection ends within the past month. I think it also relies on the hope that the first image is one of the earliest images, I suppose it could be the latest image and then this would take just as long as going through all the images.

In practice, for the image collections in the EE asset catalog, the first images are usually amongst the earliest. Note that it doesn't assume the first image is the absolutely earliest one. You are correct about the one month though. It's a threshold you would have to tweak from case to case. I don't know of any more efficient ways to do this though.
